# Unable to initialize gcloud environment

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud, gcloud-cli, google-cloud-sdk

I have google cloud sdk installed on my ubuntu 14.4system but whenever I type **gcloud init** in my console, I get the following error:-

> > rbenv: gcloud: command not found

Further if I run gcloud init with sudo the error changes to:-

> > /usr/bin/env: ruby1.9.1: No such file or directory

I am unable to understand what has google cloud sdk to do with rbenv. I tried reinstalling google cloud sdk but with the same result. Is there a way out? any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where did you install the Google Cloud SDK? Did running `gcloud` ever work? What makes you think that `rbenv` is related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On linux when you install the SDK it prompts to put following into your ~/.bashrc so PATH and such are setup to make cmds like gcloud visible

```
# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
source '/home/scott/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
source '/home/scott/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'
```

If you are not on linux/OSX then the SDK install will have similar

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though `gcloud` is not on your [$PATH](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acar).

If you installed the Cloud SDK to `/home/username/google-cloud-sdk/`, you should be able to invoke `gcloud` by running `/home/username/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud info`. If you would like to be able to run simply `gcloud`, you can run `export PATH="/home/username/google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH"` (to make this setting persist, put that command in your `~/.profile` file.